# How to fix unavailable wireless

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, iwlwifi

I have a problem with my computer. It is unable to connect or search wireless WiFi connections. At first I thought it was the WiFi card, but seems I still have the same problem after changing this card. I also checked the antenna and the cables and they seem to be working fine (The resistance is almost 0 between the terminals of the antenna and the cables make contact). I am using Linux Mint 21, and my kernel is 5.19.0-43-generic

[image: In Network Settings there are no networks shown]

If I use on the terminal the command "**inxi -nn**" the following code is obtained:

```
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlp2s0 state: down mac: ab:95:e8:4b:73:a1
  IF-ID-1: enx8eadef512204 state: unknown speed: -1 duplex: half
    mac: 7b:37:59:99:8f:97
  IF-ID-2: vpn00a94b7fbb state: unknown speed: 10 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: N/A
```

Also, if I use the command "**lspci -vv -s 02:00.0**" I obtain the following:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz (rev 1a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
        Region 0: Memory at 4f400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

What other steps can I follow in order to make the WiFi of my PC to work again?

**Edit**

After running sudo dmesg | grep iwl I obtain the following:

```
[    4.191339] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.221639] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    4.221666] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.36
[    4.222154] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.318486] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    4.480512] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded PNVM version 881c99e1
[    4.492291] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10b000
[    4.567200] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: ab:95:e8:4b:73:a1
[    4.617856] iwlwifi 0000:
```

02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0

Also after running nmcli radio it all seems to be fine, because I obtain the following:

```
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

I am guessing that maybe the mistake is related to the second line using sudo dmesg | grep iwl, but not sure about what to do next, any ideas?

Comment: Please run `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`. Are there any error messages that would seem to be related to the WiFi card or its driver?

Comment: Linux mint uses NetworkManager I believe, you could try the command `nmcli radio` to see if wifi is disabled.

Comment: Have just run both commands and put it on the main text. Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: I found a mint forum that might help you:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=380216>